# How to split large XML files into smaller ones using VBA

Tags: xml, vba, excel, xml-parsing, xmldom

Hi Below is a sample XML file format which I am working and I would like to split the file in the smaller parts. the problem is that there are 2 child node "Header" and "Records" and I am unable to save the XML file using the "Header" & "Footer" Node

```
<PortfolioBulk2_0_RES>
  <Header>
    <ProviderCode>123</ProviderCode>
    <FileID>20170817</FileID>
    <NumInputSubjects>23123</NumInputSubjects>
    <ChunkID>1</ChunkID>
    <RecordMin>1</RecordMin>
    <RecordMax>23123</RecordMax>
  </Header>
  <Record>
    <RecordId>1</RecordId>
    <ProviderSubjectNo>123456789</ProviderSubjectNo>
    <PackageLabel>GOLD</PackageLabel>
    <Error>
      <No>811</No>
      <Description>Subject not found</Description>
    </Error>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <RecordId>2</RecordId>
    <ProviderSubjectNo>654789321</ProviderSubjectNo>
    <PackageLabel>GOLD</PackageLabel>
    <Error>
      <No>811</No>
      <Description>Subject not found</Description>
    </Error>
  </Record>
  <Footer>
    <StartDateTime>2008201712:18:06</StartDateTime>
    <StopDateTime>2008201717:19:00</StopDateTime>
    <NoIndividualsOK>13185</NoIndividualsOK>
    <NoCompaniesOK>546</NoCompaniesOK>
    <NoIndividualsError>282</NoIndividualsError>
    <NoCompaniesError>20</NoCompaniesError>
    <NoUnknownsError>9090</NoUnknownsError>
  </Footer>
</PortfolioBulk2_0_RES>
```

Here is my code in VBA. I am hoping if anyone can suggest how to loop Header and Footer Nodes in Each file which is saved in the XML format. Thanks

```
Sub SPLIT()
numFiles = 2  'number of output files

Set src = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
src.async = False
src.Load "C:\Users\104704\Documents\Office 1\04_Raw Data\09_AECB Bulk\CLI working\01.xml"

Set Nodes = src.SelectNodes("//Record")
numnodes = Nodes.Length \ numFiles  'number of nodes per output file
'MsgBox (numnodes)

Set XML = Nothing
For i = 0 To Nodes.Length - 1
  'create a new XML object on the first iteration and every time numNodes
  'nodes have been added to the current object
  If i Mod numnodes = 0 Then
    If Not XML Is Nothing Then
      'if we already have an XML object: save it to a file
      Set prolog = XML.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0'")
      XML.InsertBefore prolog, XML.ChildNodes(0)
      XML.Save "C:\Users\104704\Documents\Office 1\04_Raw Data\09_AECB Bulk\CLI working\" & (i \ numnodes - 1) & ".xml"
    End If
  Set XML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
  Set root = XML.createElement("PortfolioBulk2_0_RES")

    XML.appendChild root

  End If

  root.appendChild Nodes.Item(i)
Next
'save unsaved XML object
If Not XML Is Nothing Then
  Set prolog = XML.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0'")
  XML.InsertBefore prolog, XML.ChildNodes(0)
  XML.Save "C:\Users\104704\Documents\Office 1\04_Raw Data\09_AECB Bulk\CLI working\" & (i \ numnodes - 1) & ".xml"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: A "well formed" xml file has one root tag,  So most methods in Net Library using xml allows only one root tag.  Often when xml is used in log files the log files are not well formed because the log messages are appended to the file so there are no open and close root tag making the file "not well formed".  So if you really want the file to contain multiple root tags then save the file using StreamWriter.

Comment: @O.Cheema, do you want to Export all existing record nodes into a new XML? If so what about my answer?

Answer (score 0):

@O.Cheema, as far as I understood you want to export the existing **record** nodes into a new xml.  The code below is pure VBA and uses xmldom:

```
Option Explicit
Dim src As Object
Dim XML As Object

Sub Split2()
  Dim myNodes  As Object                ' node list
  Dim nd       As Object                ' single node
  Dim myClone  As Object                ' copy of source node
  Dim i        As Integer
  Dim numNodes As Integer
  Dim numFiles As Integer: numFiles = 2  ' Output files
' wanted as root in target
  Dim tag      As String: tag = "PortfolioBulk2_0_RES"
' xml object can be defined and loaded via expression
  Dim sTarget  As String
  sTarget = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?><" & tag & ">" & vbCrLf & "</" & tag & ">"
' 1. SOURCE
' set socure file to memory
  Set src = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
  src.aSync = False
' Load source file (physically)
  src.Load ThisWorkbook.Path & "\data\unsplitted.xml"
' 2. TARGET
' set target to memory
  Set XML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
  XML.aSync = False
' Load target STRING via LoadXML method
  XML.LoadXML sTarget
' -------------------------------
' define node list in source file
' -------------------------------
  Set myNodes = src.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Record")
  numNodes = myNodes.Length \ numFiles  'number of nodes per output file
  MsgBox (numNodes)

  For Each nd In myNodes
      i = i + 1
    ' -----------------
    ' clone source node
    ' -----------------
      Set myClone = nd
    ' add to target as sub node under root tag
      XML.DocumentElement.appendchild myClone

  Next nd
  ' -----------------
  ' Save target
  ' -----------------
  XML.Save ThisWorkbook.Path & "\data\splitted(" & (i \ numNodes - 1) & ").xml"

End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

try following using xml linq

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.IO
Module Module1
    Const INPUT_FILE As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Const OUTPUT_FILE As String = "c:\temp\test1.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(INPUT_FILE)
        Dim headersAndFooters As List(Of XElement) = doc.Descendants().Where(Function(x) (x.Name.LocalName = "Header") Or (x.Name.LocalName = "Footer")).ToList()

        Dim writer As New StreamWriter(OUTPUT_FILE)

        For Each headerAndFooter In headersAndFooters
            writer.WriteLine(headerAndFooter.ToString())
        Next
        writer.Flush()
        writer.Close()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Is this in VBA?

Comment: No, that's VB.NET

Comment: Question is tagged Excel VBA

Comment: The Question is based on Excel VBA. would anyone have a solution in Excel VBA

Comment: You can register a VB.Net class project so it can be called from VBA.  See : http://smallbusiness.chron.com/use-net-class-library-excel-vba-40349.html