# Split big files into small multiple files excel VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba, split

[image]I have an XML file that is about 80MB. I constantly have to import it in Excel and do filtering in it. Sadly, it takes too long to open and sometimes crash. So I have decided to manually break it down into pieces. My steps are usually:

1. Use a software that split the files into multiple pieces. the
2. Track the starting and ending tags. The schema looks like this:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <satellite_system ntc_id="317520239" sat_name="EPFD3 (OneWeb)">
   <pfd_mask c_name="deltaLongitude" b_name="alpha" a_name="latitude" 
   type="alpha_deltaLongitude" high_freq_mhz="19300" low_freq_mhz="17800" 
   mask_id="3" refbw_khz="40">
        <by_a a = 48.5>
             <by_b b = 0>
                   <pfd c="0">-177.1175</pfd>
                    <pfd c="10">-177.3175</pfd>
              </by_b>
             <by_b b = 1>
                 <pfd c="0">-174.617</pfd>
                  <pfd c="10">-174.817</pfd>
              </by_b>
        </by_a>
    </pfd_mask>
   </satellite_system>
   ```
3. Since each new file will be imported independently into Excel, I have to make sure the opening and closing tags are included as well as the value for each tag. Because the files are split randomly at any lines.
4. Import the files into excel and filter each of them to get the highest `pfd` value.

Manually I have done that but it is time consuming. I have decided to automate that process. But all I am missing at this point to is to split the XML file into smaller pieces. I tried but failed. Now I am thinking If I turn the XML file into a text file, then would that be easier to achieve my goal. At this point what I am trying to achieve is:

1. Open the original text file and copy the first 5000 lines or so to a text file
2. Add the closing tags at the end of the file :

   ```
   </by_a>
   </pfd_mask>
   </satellite_system>
   ```
3. Save it as xxx_part1.txt
4. Somehow keep in memory the value for `by_a a` and `by_b b`
5. Copy the next 5000 lines.
6. Add the opening tags

   ```
   <satellite_system = Intelsat>
   <pfd_mask = integer_value>
   ```

   Then add the last known value for by_a a and by_ b b
   paste the 5000 lines
   then add the closing tags

   ```
   </by_a>
   </pfd_mask>
   </satellite_system>
   ```
7. Do that until the end of the original file.

This is the code I have started with:

```vb
Sub Text_file_parser()
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim txtStream As TextStream
    Dim DetFile As String
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim New_file As Object
    Dim file_path, New_filename, New_filepath As String
    Dim i, j, k As Integer
    Dim header, body, footer As Variant
    Dim File_size As Long
    
    
    DetFile = "C:\\Documents\ RDTE\test"
    sFile = Dir(DetFile & "\*.txt")
    file_path = DetFile & "\" & sFile
    
    New_filename = "New_" & sFile
    New_filepath = DetFile & "\" & New_filename
  
    Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
    Set txtStream = FSO.OpenTextFile(file_path, ForReading, False)
    
    
    'Set the number of File
    File_size = FileLen(file_path) ' remove in function
    Debug.Print File_size
    
    If Not FSO.FileExists(New_filepath) Then
    
    Set New_file = FSO.CreateTextFile(New_filepath, False, True) 
    'Do Until txtStream.AtEndOfStream
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0
    
    For i = 1 To 3
       ThisLine = txtStream.ReadLine
       'i = i + 1
       'Debug.Print "Line " & i, ThisLine
      New_file.WriteLine (ThisLine)
    
    Next
    Else
    'Set txtStream = FSO.OpenTextFile(New_filepath, ForWriting, False)
    Set New_file = FSO.OpenTextFile(New_filepath, ForWriting, False)
    For i = 1 To 3
       ThisLine = txtStream.ReadLine
       'i = i + 1
       'Debug.Print "Line " & i, ThisLine
       
       New_file.WriteLine (ThisLine)
    
    Next
    
      ' Loop
    End If
    Do While Not txtStream.AtEndOfStream
      
       'FooterLine = txtStream.ReadLine
      ' Debug.Print FooterLine
    Loop
    
    
    
    txtStream.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you considered using Power Query for that?

Comment: This question does what you are looking for, you should be able to easily adapt it to your needs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45810258/how-to-split-large-xml-files-into-smaller-ones-using-vba That being said, I think there are better tools to achieve your goal. Do you have Microsoft Access?

Comment: @Parfait, The root in my opinion is by_a. For each a value, you have by_b with multiple b values and for each b values you have multiple pfd c values.

Comment: @ Parfait, it's not the traditional style but I have no issues importing it in excel or text file. It opens fine. It does however complicate things when trying to process it using vba

Comment: @Kevin, I gave that answer a try as well but the issue is with this line 
 Set myNodes = src.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Record"). I replace Record by "by_a" and numNodes return 0. Even when I used the whole root "by_a a ="50", it does not work

Comment: @Parfait I have no issues importing the XML file whether manually or with VBA code. The issue it's too big to import and filter through in excel.
The code posted is not for importing the file into excel. It is my attempt at reading the xml file and splitting it into multiple files

Comment: @Parfait yes it is. it very much is. please see the update to the markup and the screenshot

Comment: Posted markup is still not valid. Check against any online tools (i.e., https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator). Attribute values must be quoted, `a = 48.5` and `b = 0` is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

At 80 MB which is not too large a file, consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/), the special purpose language designed to transform XML files. Specifically, you can transform directly to text files such as CSV.

Note: Below assumes all your attribute values are enclosed with quotes

```xml
<by_a a = "48.5">
<by_b b = "0">
...
<by_b b = "1">
```

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/satellite_system">
     <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(.), ',')"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
     <xsl:for-each select="pfd_mask/@*">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(.), ',')"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
     <xsl:text>by_a_a,by_b_b,pfd_c,pfd_value&#xa;</xsl:text>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::pfd"/>
  </xsl:template>
    
  <xsl:template match="pfd">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::satellite_system/@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::pfd_mask/@*"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(ancestor::by_a/@a, ',')"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(ancestor::by_b/@b, ',')"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(@c, ',')"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="satellite_system/@*|pfd_mask/@*">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ',')"/>
  </xsl:template> 
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxNakAE/1)</kbd>

**VBA** *(adjust `Sheet1` name as needed)*

```vb
Sub XML2CSV()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    ' REFERENCE Microsoft XML, v6.0 UNDER TOOLS\REFERENCES
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument, xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim newFile As String, newString As String
    
    newFile = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Output.csv"

    ' LOAD XML AND XSL DOCUMENTS
    xmlDoc.Load Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\LargeXML.xml"
    xslDoc.Load Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\XSLT_Script.xsl"

    ' TRANSFORM XML TO CSV
    xslDoc.async = False
    newString = xmlDoc.transformNode(xslDoc)
    
    ' SAVE AS CSV
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(newFile)
        .WriteLine newString
    End With

    ' IMPORT FROM CSV
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MAIN")
        With .QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & newFile, _
                          Destination:=.Range("A1"))
                     .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
                     .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
                     .Refresh
        End With
    
       .QueryTables(1).SaveData = False
       .QueryTables.Item(1).Delete
    End With
    
ExitHandle:
    Set xmlDoc = Nothing: Set xslDoc = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume ExitHandle
End Sub
```

**Output**

[image: Excel Output]

Comment: I am not sure I understand what the XLST code does and the VBA. I already made the VBA Code to import the xml file into excel. It works fine when the file is small or big. My issue is when it's too big it takes too long to open it. So breaking the xml file into smaller pieces helps opening the small files faster. I then filter out the pfd value from each small file.

Comment: Sorry it is not clear. This XSLT transforms your original XML into a CSV file which should be much smaller for import needs. See [online demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxNakAE/1). Steps: 1) save posted script as `.xsl` file onto your machine and 2) within the VBA code replace path with actual on line with "XSLT_Script.xsl". XSLT is exactly an XML file. So both are loaded the same way. Then run VBA which transforms XML, saves CSV, then imports CSV into Excel as code comments indicate and screenshot shows.

Answer (score 0):

Consider storing the file in .XLSB extension (save as -> filetype: .XLSB). It is a workbook extension type that is more efficient for larger workbooks files, and greatly improves performance. It supports all the usual functionalities, filter, table, pivot and vba etc..